# Dynamic Tabs in Maui Shell

Tags: shell, dynamic, maui

I'm trying to create an App where Tabs can be dynamically added and removed during runtime. I have a Tabbar in my AppShell.xaml, as seen in the following code sample:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="foo.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:foo"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:foo.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource ShellBackGroundColor}">
    

    <TabBar x:Name="MainTabBar">
        <ShellContent Title="Home"
                      Icon="alert_icon_2_neg.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:StartPage}">
        </ShellContent>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

The code I use to update the Tabs is the following:

```
public void UpdateTabs(ObservableCollection<UserAction> list)
{
    MainTabBar.Items.Clear();
    foreach (UserAction action in list)
    {
        MainTabBar.Items.Add(new ShellContent()
        {
            Title = action.Title,
            Icon = action.ImageSource,
            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => action.ActionPage),
            Route = action.Title
        });
    }
}
```

After this method is executed the MainTabBar.Items list has the correct shellcontents in it, however the Tabs are not displayed in the UI. How could I achieve this?

Also, I am aware of the similarities between this and a question asked by User Bagroy ([How dynamically add tabs in code behind to Maui Shell TabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73178169/how-dynamically-add-tabs-in-code-behind-to-maui-shell-tabbar)) but the solutions given in response to his question do not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, seems that using `MainTabBar.Items.Clear();` then Tabbar not display.

So the workaround here is to add this code after clear the Items,

```
MainTabBar.Items.Clear();
//add the following two lines
MainTabBar = new TabBar();
this.Items.Add(MainTabBar);
```

Hope it works for you.